# Can liquibase have configuration placeholders in sql

Tags: database, liquibase

Can liquibase have configuration placeholders in sql?

Example code:

```
<changeSet author="name" id="sql-example" runAlways="true" failOnError="true">
    <sql>SELECT schema.admin_insert('PARAMETER_PLACEHOLDER')</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Can I define parameter value in properties file; so that liquibase replace the value of the argument from a properties file ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Liquibase calls these "Changelog Parameters"

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html

A short excerpt from that page:

> Liquibase allows dynamic substitution of parameters in a changelog.
>   The parameters to replace are described using the `${parameterName}` syntax.
>
> Configuring parameter values
>
> Parameter values are looked up in the following order:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to your Liquibase runner (see Ant, command_line,
>     etc. documentation for how to pass them)
> - As a JVM system property
> - In the parameters block (`<property>` Tag) of the DatabaseChangeLog file
>     itself.

**Example**

```
<createTable tableName="${table.name}">
      <column name="id" type="int"/>
      <column name="${column1.name}" type="varchar(${column1.length})"/>
      <column name="${column2.name}" type="int"/> 
</createTable>
```

Comment: it appears `${parameterName}` substitutions do not work within a `<sql>` block

Comment: @lightswitch05 any thoughts about how to implement something like passing a placeholder parameter in to sql scripts, from <includeAll ../> tag ?

Comment: Any solutions for substitution in sql changesets ?